# Heterogeneous vs. inhomogeneous

Tags: latin, greek

I am puzzled about the word "inhomogeneous." Isn't "heterogeneous", strictly speaking, more correct? Do correct me if I'm wrong, but to me, "inhomogeneous" looks like the Latin prefix "in-" added to a Greek word. As such, it sounds a bit like "aquaphobia" to me.

Comment: What does your dictionary tell about the meanings of each, and thus how they differ?

Comment: Is the rule 'English words should not have mixed ancestry' defensible?

Comment: @Drew It tells me that both of them are the opposite of homogeneous. However, I have mostly seen "inhomogenous" used in scientific contexts.

Comment: Is that all it says? I doubt it. If the definitions are identical then either they are close synonyms or your dictionary is of no help in this case. If the descriptions are not identical, then consider how they differ. Doing that, you will find your answer...

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, no, I'm not trying to be etymologically conservative. But I must say that, given the existence of a perfectly good antonym for homogeneous with a related etymology, I think that term is preferable.

Comment: In physics (and quite likely in other sciences), people refer to something that is not homogeneous as inhomogeneous (example: the density of an object), whereas heterogeneous would be used for mixtures of different kinds or types of things.

Comment: @Drew, you only asked what *my* dictionary said. I haven't been able to find any difference in meaning there.

Comment: '_My_ dictionary' doesn't make a lot of sense when you're on the internet, with AHDEL, Collins, R H K Webster's, M-W, Wiktionary, Google Dictionary ... all readily and freely available.

Comment: I'm only trying to help you. This is how you find an answer: **consult a dictionary**. If your dictionary gives the same meaning for each, word for word, then either consult another dictionary or choose to assume that the words have identical meanings. This site is for questions you have **after** you have done such research. It is not a substitute for such research.

Comment: In what context did you see "*inhomogeneous*"? A quote would help. Anyway, I haven't seen "*inhomogeneous*", but I have seen "*nonhomogenous*", which differs from "*heterogeneous*" in the sense that it is *almost*, or, at least *partially*, homogenous, as opposed to having zero homogeneity.

Comment: _Inhomogeneous_ simply means _not homogeneous_. This covers a range of conditions, ranging from almost homogeneous to completely heterogeneous, which means made up of different things and kinds of things. The OP has an oversimplified view of word meanings, I'm afraid. One should not use _technically speaking_ without a firm grasp of the technical specs.

Comment: Whoever thought this was GR hasn't tried much original writing. See also the simple truth from Prof Lawler. above.

Comment: Should we ban "ultrasound" (latin-english/french), "hyperactive" (greek-latin), "infrared" (latin-germanic), "abnormal" (latin-greek), and thousands of useful words for being of heterogeneous ancestry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two words you name do indeed seem very similar in meaning, but they can serve different purposes in practice. The usefulness of *inhomogeneous* becomes evident in discussions of variation from a norm or ideal of homogeneity, where the departure from homogeneity may constitute *inhomogeneity*, while the state of complete nonhomogeneity may be termed *heterogeneity*.

For example, A.F. Buddington, "[On Some Natural and Synthetic Melilites](http://books.google.com/books?id=MlQtgbQmRgUC&pg=PA61&dq=%22inhomogeneous%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=fwAJVLfALsS6iwLelYDABg&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22inhomogeneous%22&f=false)," in *American Journal of Science* (January 1922), in a discussion of the crystalline states of certain chemical mixtures, refers to different mixtures as "homogeneous," "inhomogeneous," or "heterogeneous." Buddington is clearly aware of the word *heterogeneous*, since he uses it; but he finds the term *inhomogeneous* valuable as a way to describe crystalline formations that (in a series of experiments where conditions are varied slightly but systematically) conspicuously cease to be homogeneous.

The vast majority of matches in a Google Books search for *inhomogeneous* occur in highly technical scientific articles where, presumably, shades of distinction with regard to homogeneity and heterogeneity are especially important.

It's true that many authors use *inhomogeneous* without also using *heterogeneous*, but perhaps in those cases using a negative of *homogeneous* keeps the concept of homogeneity—and its absence—more centrally in view than would be the case if *heterogeneous* were used in place of *inhomogeneous*. I certainly wouldn't assume that a writer was using *inhomogeneous* due to a simple lack of familiarity with the word *heterogeneous*.

In many cases, of course, authors don't want to put homogeneity (or variance from homogeneity) in the spotlight, in which case *heterogeneous* may be a better word choice than *inhomogeneous*.

Answer (score 0):

There are a fairly large number of English words that are half Greek and half Latin, e.g. sociology (L+G), television (G+L), homosexuality (G+L), etc., etc. I, as a purist, have my doubts about all these words, but in this particular forum everything is all right as long as it has enough million google hits….